# Stop process using a button

Tags: c#, user-interface, progress-bar

I created a "loading window", where during a process a progress bar appears, after the end of the process this window disappears.
The process in my Tool takes 2, 3 Minutes. I want to implement a button that when the Tool has started the process can be interrupted via this button.

```
    public partial class LoadingWindow : Form
    {        
        public Action Worker { get; set; }       
        public LoadingWindow(Action worker)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (worker == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            Worker = worker;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

        private void btnStopProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea, what to implement in btnStopProcess_Click function (...) ?

Comment: Is it Winforms/WPF?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Winforms

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen any solution ?

Comment: @Tidra To make it clear: The solution you're looking for does not exist. Tasks can only be terminated cooperatively. Forcing a task to terminate from the outside is not possible. In .NET framework you could kill a `Thread`, but even that is no longer possible in .NET 5+.

Comment: Using a cancellationToken as PMF suggest is absolutely the way to go. But you should also consider some way to inform the caller if the method succeeded, failed or was canceled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to adapt your worker accordingly, because the task must be able to "assist" that it can be terminated.

```cs
    public partial class LoadingWindow : Form
    {        
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancel;
        public Action<CancellationToken> Worker { get; set; }       
        public LoadingWindow(Action<CancellationToken> worker)
        {
            _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
            InitializeComponent();
            if (worker == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            Worker = worker;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Worker(_cancel.Token)).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

        private void btnStopProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _cancel.Cancel(); // Inform worker that abort was pressed.
        }
    }
```

And then, in your worker, regularly test whether the token is cancelled and abort if so. You may need to forward it to the methods that get called from there.

[You might also want to remove the setter from the `Worker` property. Changing the worker while the window is already visible will result in weird behavior]

Comment: thanks, but Worker (type: Action<CancellationToken>) can not be equal with worker (type: Action)!

Comment: and _cancel = new CancellationTokenSource; should have arguments

Comment: @Tidra Sure for the second point, fixed that.

Comment: at the first point I mean Worker = worker (The compiler should give an error here)

Comment: Oh, true. Fixed that one as well, thanks.

Comment: as input at the LoadingWindow constructor I have a void function (actually), is there any way to convert method group in Action<CancellationToken> worker!!

Comment: You should change that void function to take a `CancellationToken` as argument, otherwise the whole change is useless. If you can't do that for some cases (assuming you use this dialog for different operations), you can still create a function taking the argument that calls into the one without the argument. But as said, that's quite useless then.